# Why can I not attach DOM events to my Google map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, dom

I have a mockup here

http://jsfiddle.net/tF3Yq/1/

I have used the following function `addDomListener` like this

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById("my-button", 'click', function(e) {
        alert('clicked');
    }));
```

But clicking does not appear to do anything

Comment: it is best to include the relevant code parts in your question..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has to be :

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById("my-button"), 'click', function(e) {
        alert('clicked');
    });
```

...instead of:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById("my-button", 'click', function(e) {
        alert('clicked');
    }));
```

With your current code you pass the parameters event-type and the callback to `getElementById()` and not to `google.maps.event`